# Submit multiple html forms to vbscript function

Tags: html, forms, function, vbscript

Trying to submit multiple html forms to one vbscript function. The purpose of the function is to update a text file. Depending on the text area submitted for updating should dictate which text file the function updates. Basically just need one function to handle file updates for all the text areas. Here is a code snippet.

The onload function loads the text currently in the text files to the text areas.

The F1 and F2 functions copy the text areas to the clipboard. Basically this is just a simple quick reference clipboard.

You can see how I actually need to apply this concept to every function. Several forms all submitting to single functions (read, write, and copy).

```
<head>
<title>Quick Comments</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Quick Comments"
     SCROLL="YES"
>
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
    sub Window_onLoad()
        set oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set oFile=oFSO.OpenTextFile("signature.txt",1)
        text=oFile.ReadAll
        document.all.var1.value=text
        oFile.Close
        set oFile=oFSO.OpenTextFile("initial.txt",1)
        text=oFile.ReadAll
        document.all.var2.value=text
        oFile.Close
    end sub
    sub FileUpdate
        Dim TheForm
        Set TheForm = Document.field1
        Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("signature.txt",2,true)
        objFileToWrite.WriteLine(TheForm.signature.value)
        objFileToWrite.Close
        Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
    end sub
    sub F1
        Dim TheForm
        Set TheForm = Document.field1
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & TheForm.signature.value & " | clip", 0, TRUE
    end sub
    sub F2
        Dim TheForm
        Set TheForm = Document.field2
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & TheForm.initial.value & " | clip", 0, TRUE
    end sub
</script>
<body>
    <h1>Quick Comments</h1><hr>
    <form id="field1" name="field1">
        <textarea name="var1" id='signature' cols=75 rows=8></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="F1" language="vbscript">
        <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="FileUpdate" language="vbscript">
    </form>
    <form id="field2" name="field2">
        <textarea name="var2" id='initial' cols=75 rows=8></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="F2" language="vbscript">
        <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="F1" language="vbscript">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below examples based on your code. There are separate procs `WriteTextFile` and `ReadTextFile` for read-write ops, also I switched to `window.clipboardData.SetData` clipboard control method. I suppose that text files located in the same folder as HTA, the path to that folder is stored in `strHtaFolder` variable. Note that `<textarea>` tag `.name` property is used to get the filename to update.

First one uses `window.event.srcElement.parentNode.childNodes(0)` to retrieve the necessary `<textarea>` node from the current `event` object:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quick Comments</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION 
        ID="oHTA"
        APPLICATIONNAME="Quick Comments"
        SCROLL="YES"
    >
    </head>
    <script language="VBScript">

        Dim strHtaFolder

        Sub Window_onLoad()
            strHtaFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(Replace(oHTA.commandLine, """", "")) & "\"
            document.all.signature.value = ReadTextFile(strHtaFolder & "signature.txt", -2) ' -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
            document.all.initial.value = ReadTextFile(strHtaFolder & "initial.txt", -2)
        End Sub

        Sub FileUpdate()
            Dim objForm, objTextArea
            Set objForm = window.event.srcElement.parentNode
            Set objTextArea = objForm.childNodes(0)
            WriteTextFile objTextArea.value, strHtaFolder & objTextArea.name & ".txt", -2
        End Sub

        Sub CopyText()
            Dim objForm, objTextArea
            Set objForm = window.event.srcElement.parentNode
            Set objTextArea = objForm.childNodes(0)
            window.clipboardData.SetData "text", objTextArea.value
        End Sub

        Function ReadTextFile(strPath, lngFormat)
            ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
            With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, False, lngFormat)
                ReadTextFile = ""
                If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
                .Close
            End With
        End Function

        Sub WriteTextFile(strContent, strPath, lngFormat)
            ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
            With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 2, True, lngFormat)
                .Write (strContent)
                .Close
            End With
        End Sub

    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>Quick Comments</h1><hr>
        <form id="field1" name="field1">
            <textarea name="signature" id='signature' cols=75 rows=8></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="CopyText()" language="vbscript">
            <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="FileUpdate()" language="vbscript">
        </form>
        <form id="field2" name="field2">
            <textarea name="initial" id='initial' cols=75 rows=8></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="CopyText()" language="vbscript">
            <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="FileUpdate()" language="vbscript">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the second example slightly changed. It stores on window load both signature and initial elements to an array, and later when the button pressed it just passes the index of the element in that array to the sub when event occurs:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quick Comments</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION 
        ID="oHTA"
        APPLICATIONNAME="Quick Comments"
        SCROLL="YES"
    >
    </head>
    <script language="VBScript">

        Dim strHtaFolder, arrItems

        Sub Window_onLoad()
            arrItems = Array(document.all.signature, document.all.initial)
            strHtaFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(Replace(oHTA.commandLine, """", "")) & "\"
            arrItems(0).value = ReadTextFile(strHtaFolder & "signature.txt", -2) ' -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
            arrItems(1).value = ReadTextFile(strHtaFolder & "initial.txt", -2)
        End Sub

        Sub FileUpdate(strItem)
            WriteTextFile arrItems(strItem).value, strHtaFolder & arrItems(strItem).name & ".txt", -2
        End Sub

        Sub CopyText(strItem)
            window.clipboardData.SetData "text", arrItems(strItem).value
        End Sub

        Function ReadTextFile(strPath, lngFormat)
            ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
            With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, False, lngFormat)
                ReadTextFile = ""
                If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
                .Close
            End With
        End Function

        Sub WriteTextFile(strContent, strPath, lngFormat)
            ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
            With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 2, True, lngFormat)
                .Write (strContent)
                .Close
            End With
        End Sub

    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>Quick Comments</h1><hr>
        <form id="field1" name="field1">
            <textarea name="signature" id='signature' cols=75 rows=8></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="CopyText(0)" language="vbscript">
            <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="FileUpdate(0)" language="vbscript">
        </form>
        <form id="field2" name="field2">
            <textarea name="initial" id='initial' cols=75 rows=8></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="copy" value="Copy" onclick="CopyText(1)" language="vbscript">
            <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="FileUpdate(1)" language="vbscript">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

BTW, use of `<form>` tags isn't necessary, you might use e. g. `<div>` tags instead.